# How to call function from view with selected from some select item as argument?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How I can achieve this?:

```
<select>
 <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="item">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
<a ng-click="foo(item)">Action</a>
```

Foo is declared in angular controller this way:

```
$scope.foo = function(item) {
 console.log(item);
}
```

I understand, that `item` is defined in element `<option>` scope. But I need to send currently selected item to `foo` foonction. How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `ng-repeat`, use `ng-options` instead:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items" >
</select>
```

Then, you should be able to use this:

```
<a ng-click="foo(selectedItem)">Action</a>
```

This works because `ng-model` sets `$scope.selectedItem` to the currently selected item in the dropdown.

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ro6wvoL8/12/)

Comment: So, @SharikovVladislav, did this answer help?

Comment: May be. I will be able to try it only tomorrow

Comment: I made two examples. [My code](http://jsfiddle.net/ro6wvoL8/11/) and [yours](http://jsfiddle.net/ro6wvoL8/12/). Your code realy working perfectly. But why? What is wrong with mine? In my code `ng-selected` sets `$scope.selectedItem`, but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: I am asking this, because I'd already tried additional `$scope` variable with my code and it didn't help me.

Comment: `ng-selected` is a attribute to use on `<option>` elements, not on `<select>`. With `ng-selected`, you can make a certain option "selected". It doesn't save the selection to a scope variable.